# A MNC with maximum property but not singular

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Let $E$ be a Banach space, $\mathfrak{M}_E$ indicate the family of all nonempty bounded subset of $E$,  $\mathfrak{N}_E$ the family of all relatively compact sets, and $Ker \mu=\{X\in \mathfrak{M}_E$ such that: $\mu(X)=0\}$.

> **"Standard" Definition:**
> A mapping $\mu:\mathfrak{M}_E\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ is said to be a [**measure of noncompactness**](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/105982/CommentatMathUnivCarol_021-1980-1_10.pdf) (shortly, MNC) in $E$ if it satisfies the following conditions (for any $X,Y,X_n \in \mathfrak{M}_E$ and $a\in E$):
>
> 1. The family $\operatorname{ker} \mu $ is nonempty and $\operatorname{ker} \mu \subset \mathfrak{N}_E$.
> 2. $X\subseteq Y\Rightarrow  \mu (X)\leq \mu (Y)$.
> 3. $\mu (\bar{X})=\mu (X)$.
> 4. $\mu (\operatorname{Conv}(X))=\mu (X)$.
> 5. $\mu (\lambda X+(1-\lambda) Y)\leq \lambda \mu (X)+(1-\lambda) \mu(Y)$ for $\lambda\in [0,1]$.
> 6. If $\{X_n\}\subset \mathfrak{M}_E^c$, such  that $X_{n+1}\subset X_n$ for $n=1,2,...$ and if $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu(X_n)=0$ then $X_{\infty}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}X_n\neq \emptyset$.

---

Now, an MNC is said to be:

7. With **maximum property** if: $\mu(X \cup Y)=\max \{\mu(X), \mu(Y)\}$.
8. **Nonsingular** if: $\mu(\{a\} \cup X)=\mu(X)$.

---

In this question, I want to see if there is an MNC that is With maximum property but **Not** nonsingular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, according to [paper you cited](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/105982/CommentatMathUnivCarol_021-1980-1_10.pdf), $\mathfrak{M}_E$ is **the** [not "a"] family of all nonempty bounded subset**s** of $E$.
2. The examples of MNC's given in the [paper you cited](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/105982/CommentatMathUnivCarol_021-1980-1_10.pdf) -- namely, the Kuratowski MNC $\alpha$, the ball measure $\chi$, and the MNC $\mu$ defined in Theorem 1 of that paper -- are all with the maximum property and nonsingular.
3. Perhaps, you rather wanted an MNC with the maximum property but not **non**singular. Such an MNC, say $\nu$, is given e.g. by the formula $\nu(X):=\sup\{|x|\colon x\in X\}$ for $E=\mathbb R$ and all $X\in\mathfrak{M}_E$.

Comment: Many Thanks. For 1. and 2. it's a "typing error". Good example, I will check the properties